# Why is that with Visual Studio code the function declaration in header file not required?

Tags: c, visual-c++, extern

I am using MSVC. Earlier I used Code Blocks where to share functions across files one need to put the declaration of that shared function in a header file. But with MSVC we don't need to do that, why? Is it because MSVC does that work for us behind the scenes? Also now I have to specify mutiple .c files that are to be compiled in the tasks.json file.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    add(2,5);
    return 0;
}
```

utilities.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add(int a, int b) {
    printf("sum: %d\n", a+b);
}
```

Output:
With MSVC: sum: 7

With Code Blocks:
implicit declaration of function 'add'
undefined reference to function 'add'

Why such difference in outputs?

Comment: The latter, *"undefined reference to function 'add'"* is because your project is misconfigured in code blocks and you never included `utilities.c` in the project files to be compiled *and* linked. Regarding the former, I suspect you don't have warnings enabled at a sufficient level to where MSVC will tell you `add` is implicitly being declared as `int add()` (which legacy C compilers will do in some twisted effort to be helpful when reality is anything-but). Of course, your configuration options aren't shown in your question, so that's all just a wild guess.

Comment: implicit declaration of a function from C whereas you might compile in C++ mode in CB (or with different flags)

Answer (score 0):

Let's turn chaos into order:

1. `implicit declaration of function 'func'`

This is a **compiler** warning, telling you that the exact prototype of function `func` is unknown at the time of the compilation of **this specific source file** into an object code.

The compiler "lets you off" with a warning, assuming that the aforementioned function is implemented in some other source file, and that the linker will later be able to link between the object code of the current source file, and the object code of that other source file.

2. `undefined reference to function 'func'`

This is a **linker** error, telling you that the assumption previously made by the compiler was... well, you know what they say about assumptions...

Anyway, as you may have understood by know, turning your source code into an executable image requires these two steps, executed **sequentially** (i.e., one after the other, and not in parallel):

1. Compilation of each source file into an object code
2. Linkage of all the object codes into an executable image

Comment: I appreciate your replies and it gave me hints to resolve my problem. When I went back to Code Blocks I saw that I missed to check mark the Debug and Release check boxes under the Build Target section. As a result the object file(utilities.o) wasn't being added to either of the Debug or Release folders and during the linking stage the linker wasn't able to find a .o file which contains the add(int a, int b) definition. Also I found that creating a header file is just a convenience for not having to declare the shared functions multiple times at the place of its use.